# How to allocate one ID to another and show this in HTML

Tags: php, html, database

For my iPhone web app I have created a database in php MyAdmin, it contains two tables (bookings, waiters and allocations) the I wish to view the bookings within a table in HTML where i can allocate a waiter to that booking. Any tips on how this would be done, any help will be appreciated as this is my first contact with web app development and MyAdmin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql work with autoincrement id. You will have an id after of an insertion. You can to create a table only to id's and after to use it in the insertion of the waiter.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to get the data from the table via MySQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Then you would loop through the result

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
extract($row);
}
```

Then you can do as you wish with the returned data...

You really need to give us a little more... What have you got so far?